Hide Bullet Points in Org Mode Export to PDF and Available Properties
I'm using Org mode with Emacs and exporting to PDF. I want to hide bullet points in my export.
* Recommandations (bullet to be hidden)
  some text or src_comment headers

* Title1
** Subtitle1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :UNNUMBERED: t
   :END:

Could you please advise on how to achieve this? I tried using :HIDDEN: t by chance but it didn't have any effect. Additionally, is there an exhaustive list of properties available? I couldn't find any information regarding "UNNUMBERED," for example. Thank you!

C-h i g(org)i unnumbered RET will consult the Org manual (g(org)) and search the index i for unnumbered. That same section of the manual describes the most important export settings. BTW, what do you mean by bullet points? How are they distinguished from non-bullet-points?

At the top of the document, I want to include some notes or examples
of LaTeX headers for use when editing the document. I'd like to use an
org-mode bullet point list where the content can be collapsed by
pressing the Tab key, for easier navigation through the
document. Essentially, I want a #+begin_comments block that won't be
edited at the export, but with an org-mode bullet system for collapsible sections when needed. I hope that makes sense.

You can use a regular heading and tag it :noexport. Inside that heading you can do whatever you want: the section will just not be exported. Is that what you need?

Wahoo. That's it! Great. Thanks a lot NickD. I learned something really usefull. I'm still stunned. I didn't used tags that much, I should look more. Thanks again, this is the perfert answer to my problem.
I used it like this, and the tagged bullet and text doesn't appear at the export.
* some notes :noexport:
  here is my notes. This won't be export

* header
  This will be export

* header
  This too

